# Notice: Undefined index : PHP

Tags: php

estoy aprendiendo PHP por mi cuenta y me tope con este error...

> (Notice: Undefined index: nombre in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\guardar.php on
> line 3
>
> Notice: Undefined index: apellido in C:\xampp\htdocs\pdo\guardar.php
> on line 4

Fallo inesperado, no se guardo la información)

favor de su ayuda, intente solucionarlo con asi...

```
$nombre = (isset($_POST['nombre']);
$apellido = (isset($_POST['apellido']);
```

pero sigo teniendo problemas para despues visualizar los datos de la tabla que generé para mostrar estos datos.

```html
<?php
include 'conexion.php';
$nombre = $_POST['nombre'];
$apellido = $_POST['apellido'];


$ins = $con->prepare("INSERT INTO personas VALUES (DEFAULT, :nombre, :ape) ");
$ins->bindparam(':nombre',$nombre);
$ins->bindparam(':ape',$apellido);

if($ins->execute()){
    echo "Guardado con exito";
}else{
    echo" Fallo inesperado, no se guardo la información";
}

?>
```

Comment: erick tenes un formulario donde se envían los datos? o como lo has realizado

Comment: Si, parece que los name de los formularios no coincide con el archivo php